# Steam on the water

Tags: thermodynamics

When I turn off the gas, water sends one last "steam wave" and then it stops boiling immediately. Why?

Note: the water boils in a steel kettle.

Comment: can you take a video of it ?

Answer (score 2):

If it's visible, it's not steam. Strictly, steam is (invisible) water vapor. The "wave" you see is from a *decrease* in heat flux (because you turned the heat off), which causes the actual steam emerging from the kettle to cool and condense into a cloud of liquid water droplets.